# Autohotkey Setting A_Scriptdir Based On Different Script Locations on Different Computers

Tags: autohotkey

I have several different computers that have an extra drive F:\dropbox\autohotkey or c:\dropbox\autohotkey or a remapped b:\ drive.
I want to create a startup script to determine which drive exists, set it to A_Scriptdir, and execute a file.
This is a script created by ChatGPT with an array. It does not work yet, but it added an array to determine which location to execute.

It does not work correctly. any help would be greatly appreciated.

#noenv
#SingleInstance, force

#noenv
#SingleInstance, force

#requires autohotkey v1

```
setscriptdir()

SetScriptDir()
{
    static scriptDir := ""
    if (scriptDir != "")
    {
        scriptDir := A_ScriptDir
    ;~ A_ScriptDir := scriptDir
        return
    }
    pathArray := ["b:\", "f:\dropbox\autohotkey", "c:\dropbox\autohotkey"]
    loop % pathArray.Length()
    {
        path := pathArray[A_Index]
    ;~ MsgBox %path%
        if FileExist(path . "\" . bbb-1-myahkdefault.ahk)
        {
            scriptDir := path
            scriptDir := A_ScriptDir
            MsgBox %scriptDir%
            ;~A_ScriptDir := scriptDir
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "It does not work correctly" mean?

Comment: When I execute the script, it steps through the directories but never executes  bbb-1-myahkdefault.ahk  Any help would be greatly appreciated.